# MySQL losing variable value

Tags: mysql, variables

Example:
create table test, 2 fields
id int(11)
comment varchar(15)

populate with id from 1 to 32
set comment to 'test' for all rows

execute the following query:

```
SET @val1 := 'test'; 
SELECT *
FROM test AS r 
WHERE r.comment = @val1;
```

it shows the first 30 rows, when you change page it tells no rows are found

I can reproduce this with any table and parameter in my MySQL

Any idea why this happens?

With left table join it states the joined table fields are NULL

MySQL 5.0.96-0ubuntu3 used through Phpmyadmin

Comment: Try what happens if you just simply use `'test'` in the `where` clause instead of a variable. My guess is that phpmyadmin does not execute the `set` statement the 2nd time, only the select with different limit and the connection is closed between the two calls, therefore `val1` will be an empty variable in the 2nd call - therefore there are no matches. You can enable the query log on your MySQL server and see for yourself what queries phpmyadmin actually executes.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I solved it by using 'test' in the where clause. But I don't see the point in having variables in MySQL then.
Thank you for pointing one can check the query log!

Comment: Phpmyadmin by default uses non-persistent connection to mysql. The session variable you use exists for the duration of the connection (session). First, phpmyadmin executes the 2 statements and `@val1` is populated, so the select returns the expected results. Then phpmyadmin closes the connection and `@val1` does not exist any longer. Then you execute the select for the 2nd time. Phpmyadmin opens a new connection, but then executes only the select statement for the paging. So, there is nothing wrong with the mysql session variables, phpmyadmin's behaviour is the root cause.

Comment: You can enable persistent connections in phpmyadmin and then `@val1` will exist when you run the query for the 2nd time.